# How to keep both button text and payload in whatsapp quick reply message template

Tags: whatsapp

Whatsapp quick reply request template has option for payload only. In what option we can configure the button text. After lots of searching on internet I did not find proper solution.

Here is the json of button which need to be send in request but it only has the payload option

```
  {
                "type": "button",
                "sub_type" : "quick_reply",
                "index": "0", 
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "payload",
                        # Business Developer-defined payload
                        "payload":"aGlzIHRoaXMgaXMgY29vZHNhc2phZHdpcXdlMGZoIGFTIEZISUQgV1FEV0RT"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Reference link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/message-templates/interactive-message-templates#request

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure that in the Facebook Business Manager UI or in the Graph API post request when you create the template. When you're sending the message, you can't dynamically configure the text.

Comment: that's correct. Only the payload can be changed